# How to change the color of svg objects imported into raphaeljs from corel?

Tags: javascript, raphael, coreldraw

I imported a .svg file into raphael and I would like to be able to change the fill colors and stroke colors of the shapes.

```
my_set = my_paper.importSVG( my_svgXML ) ;

for( var i = 0 ; i < my_set.length ; i++ )
  { var lvo_element  = my_set[ i ] ; 
    lvo_element.attr( { 'fill'    :  '#fafafa' } ) ;

    console.log( lvo_element.attrs.fill ) ; 
    // correctly outputs  '#fafafa'  
  }
```

... but the elements' colors are not updating. However, lvo_element.glow() does work.

---

**EDIT:**
fabricjs requires a .renderAll() call after any property changes ... but I do not see anything in raphael docs that seems similar to that, such as 'update'

---

**NOTE:**

- I used jquery.ajax to load my.svg into app
- I used raphael-svg-import.js for importing it into raphael
- I have tried non-object notation also: lvo_element.attr('fill', '#fafafa' ) ;

Comment: try `'stroke'` instead of `fill`. see if it works

Comment: A.S., thanks for responding  .... I have tried 'stroke' also, but it also did not respond.

Comment: Your code works for me, what version of Raphael are you using? Which version of raphael-svg-import.js? I tried Raphael 2.1.0, import (classic) 0.1.3

Comment: SpaceDog ... thanks ... you sent me in the right direction .... I was focused on the raphael library, but the problem was my svg (which is exported from corel and was including an internal style sheet) ... I created an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to .svg from CorelDesignerX5, there is a Styling Options pulldown box which defaults to Internal StyleSheet. This thus creates a internal stylesheet in the exported svg, which just causes all kinds of problems, at least with the raphael library.

Change the *Styling Options* to **Presentation Attributes**.